# Foreach Duplicating Results?

Tags: javascript, json, face-recognition

I'm getting a JSON from the Face Detection API of Microsoft Recognition Services and displaying the results. I have already created several results and this is the only one that is quadruple the collapsible.

The size of the JSON object is 9, from 0 ~ 8. It is creating more than 50 objects, 5 for each person.

The right thing is to create a collapsible for each person, which will give 9 results.

> [image: Length] [image: duplicate]
>
> **CODE:**

```
function GenerateAttributes__(objJSON){
  var count = 0;
  for(obj in objJSON){
    for(hair in objJSON[obj].faceAttributes.hair.hairColor){
      document.getElementById('face-attributes-information').innerHTML +=

      '<ul class="collapsible" data-collapsible="accordion">' +
        '<li>' +
          '<div class="collapsible-header"><i class="fa fa-id-card-o" aria-hidden="true"></i><strong>People (2)</strong></div>' +

          '<div class="collapsible-body white">' +
            '<ul class="collection">' +
              '<li class="collection-item avatar">' +
                '<img class="responsive-img circle pink" src="img/neoris-icons/moustache.png">' +
                '<span class="title title-collection-content-information">Facial Appearance</span>' +
                '<p><strong>Moustache</strong></p>' +
                '<a href="#!" class="secondary-content">' +
                  '<span class="new black badge" data-badge-caption=" "><strong>1.0 %</strong></span>' +
                  '<span class="new black badge" data-badge-caption=" "><strong>Confidence </strong></span>' +
                '</a>' +
              '</li>' +

              '<li class="collection-item avatar">' +
                '<i class="fa fa-question-circle circle red" aria-hidden="true"></i>' +
                '<img class="responsive-img circle pink" src="img/neoris-icons/beard.png">' +
                '<p><strong>Beard</strong></p>' +
                '<a href="#!" class="secondary-content">' +
                  '<span class="new black badge" data-badge-caption=" "><strong>1.0 %</strong></span>' +
                  '<span class="new black badge" data-badge-caption=" "><strong>Confidence </strong></span>' +
                '</a>' +
              '</li>' +

              '<li class="collection-item avatar">' +
                '<img class="responsive-img circle pink" src="img/neoris-icons/sideburns.png">' +
                '<span class="title title-collection-content-information">Facial Appearance</span>' +
                '<p><strong>Sideburns</strong></p>' +
                '<a href="#!" class="secondary-content">' +
                  '<span class="new black badge" data-badge-caption=" "><strong>1.0 %</strong></span>' +
                  '<span class="new black badge" data-badge-caption=" "><strong>Confidence </strong></span>' +
                '</a>' +
              '</li>' +
            '</ul>' +
          '</div>' +

          '<div class="collapsible-body white">' +
            '<ul class="collection">' +
              '<li class="collection-item avatar">' +
                '<img class="responsive-img circle brown" src="img/neoris-icons/female-hair.png">' +
                '<span class="title title-collection-content-information">Hair Color</span>' +
                '<p><strong class="brown-text">Brown</strong></p>' +
                '<a href="#!" class="secondary-content">' +
                  '<span class="new brown badge" data-badge-caption=" "><strong>1.0 %</strong></span>' +
                  '<span class="new brown badge" data-badge-caption=" "><strong>Confidence </strong></span>' +
                '</a>' +
              '</li>' +

              '<li class="collection-item avatar">' +
                '<img class="responsive-img circle yellow accent-4" src="img/neoris-icons/female-hair.png">' +
                '<span class="title title-collection-content-information">Hair Color</span>' +
                '<p><strong class="yellow-text">Blond</strong></p>' +
                '<a href="#!" class="secondary-content">' +
                  '<span class="new yellow accent-4 badge" data-badge-caption=" "><strong>1.0 %</strong></span>' +
                  '<span class="new yellow accent-4 badge" data-badge-caption=" "><strong>Confidence </strong></span>' +
                '</a>' +
              '</li>' +

              '<li class="collection-item avatar">' +
                '<img class="responsive-img circle black" src="img/neoris-icons/female-hair.png">' +
                '<span class="title title-collection-content-information">Hair Color</span>' +
                '<p><strong class="black-text">Black</strong></p>' +
                '<a href="#!" class="secondary-content">' +
                  '<span class="new black badge" data-badge-caption=" "><strong>1.0 %</strong></span>' +
                  '<span class="new black badge" data-badge-caption=" "><strong>Confidence </strong></span>' +
                '</a>' +
              '</li>' +

              '<li class="collection-item avatar">' +
                '<img class="responsive-img circle teal" src="img/neoris-icons/female-hair.png">' +
                '<span class="title title-collection-content-information">Hair Color</span>' +
                '<p><strong class="teal-text">Other</strong></p>' +
                '<a href="#!" class="secondary-content">' +
                  '<span class="new badge" data-badge-caption=" "><strong>1.0 %</strong></span>' +
                  '<span class="new badge" data-badge-caption=" "><strong>Confidence </strong></span>' +
                '</a>' +
              '</li>' +

              '<li class="collection-item avatar">' +
                '<img class="responsive-img circle grey" src="img/neoris-icons/female-hair.png">' +
                '<span class="title title-collection-content-information">Hair Color</span>' +
                '<p><strong class="grey-text">Gray</strong></p>' +
                '<a href="#!" class="secondary-content">' +
                  '<span class="new grey badge" data-badge-caption=" "><strong>1.0 %</strong></span>' +
                  '<span class="new grey badge" data-badge-caption=" "><strong>Confidence </strong></span>' +
                '</a>' +
              '</li>' +

              '<li class="collection-item avatar">' +
                '<img class="responsive-img circle red" src="img/neoris-icons/female-hair.png">' +
                '<span class="title title-collection-content-information">Hair Color</span>' +
                '<p><strong class="red-text">Red</strong></p>' +
                '<a href="#!" class="secondary-content">' +
                  '<span class="new red badge" data-badge-caption=" "><strong>1.0 %</strong></span>' +
                  '<span class="new red badge" data-badge-caption=" "><strong>Confidence </strong></span>' +
                '</a>' +
              '</li>' +

            '</ul>' +
          '</div>' +

        '</li>' +
      '</ul>';

      console.log("COUNT OBJ: ", count++);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: What does a `objJSON[obj].faceAttributes.hair.hairColor` look like? Without seeing the full JSON structure this question is hard to answer. Also, you shouldn't use `for..in` to iterate over an array or an object. It's much safer to follow a different strategy: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/500504/why-is-using-for-in-with-array-iteration-a-bad-idea

Comment: seems like for()for()count++ so 5 * hairccolor count?

Answer (score 0):

You're interacting one loop inside another, he's acting 1 * (n), 2 * (n), 3 * (n).
Review your logic